# Bind Xuni Calendar SelectionChanging event to ViewModel (Xamarin Forms with Prism)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

i want to use the [Xuni calendar control](http://www.goxuni.com/calendar/) in my Xamarin Forms app (Prism).
How can i bind the SelectionChanging event of the calendar control to a command in my ViewModel using [Prism](http://brianlagunas.com/) because i don't want to use code behind.
That's my XAML so far.

```
<xuni:XuniCalendar x:Name="calendar" MaxSelectionCount="-1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <xuni:XuniCalendar.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="SelectionChanging" Command="{Binding SelectionChangingCommand}"
                              EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource selectionChangingEventArgsConverter}" />
    </xuni:XuniCalendar.Behaviors>
</xuni:XuniCalendar>
```

This is my converter:

```
public class SelectionChangingEventArgsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var selectionChangingEventArgs = value as CalendarSelectionChangingEventArgs;
        if (selectionChangingEventArgs == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected value to be of type SelectionChangingEventArgs", nameof(value));
        }
        return selectionChangingEventArgs.SelectedDates;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here's the Command in my ViewModel:

```
public DelegateCommand SelectionChangingCommand => new DelegateCommand(SelectionChanging);

private void SelectionChanging()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I do not get any errors but the SelectionChangingCommand in the ViewModel is not triggered.

Thanks,
Uwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to create a converter, you just need to specify the Command, Event name and EventArgs path `SelectedDates`.

```
<xuni:XuniCalendar MaxSelectionCount="-1" 
                   Grid.Row="0" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <xuni:XuniCalendar.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="SelectionChanging" 
                                  Command="{Binding SelectionChangingCommand}"
                                  Path="SelectedDates" />
    </xuni:XuniCalendar.Behaviors>
</xuni:XuniCalendar>
```

In your ViewModel you need to use the generic DelegateCommand to accept the parameter. According to the [docs](http://www.goxuni.com/docs/xamarin/) SelectedDates is a `List<DateTime>` so you would need the following in your ViewModel

```
public DelegateCommand<List<DateTime>> SelectionChangingCommand { get; }

public void OnSelectionChangingCommandExecuted(List<DateTime> selectedDates)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: That works great. Thanks! I only had to replace "Path" with "EventArgsParameterPath" to get it running.